# How to decrease content length of WPF Context Menu Item

Tags: wpf

I am learning WPF and creating Breadcrumb like window explorer.
but facing issue with setting of breadcrumb context menu item length. I wanted to fix the character length of menu item 50 and when character length is more than 50 then eliminate extra characters and set ... at last like below image

my menu item code:

```
    <ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding UserName }"                                                     
            FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="11"
            Height="22" Margin="-22,-20,-40,-20"                                                
            Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.SelectObject,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle}">
        <MenuItem.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Content="{Binding UserName}">
            </ToolTip>
        </MenuItem.ToolTip>
        </MenuItem>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

[image: This is the image from windows explorer breadcrumb. that I want to make]

[image: This is the image of my WPF breadcrumb]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the better way for context menu item header content width decrease with ... at last when exceed from particular width using char ellipsis control like below,

```
<MenuItem FontSize="11" Height="22" Margin="-18,-20,-40,-20"                                                                                   
Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.CrumbSelectObject,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
          AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding}">
<!-- char ellipsis control -->
<MenuItem.Header>
   <TextBlock MaxWidth="150" 
        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
        Text="{Binding UserName}" 
        FontFamily="Arial" 
        FontSize="11">
    </TextBlock>
</MenuItem.Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create another property to show on header :

```
    public string ShortUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserName.Length > 50) ? UserName.Substring(0, 47) + "..." : UserName;
        }
    }


    <MenuItem Header="{Binding ShortUserName }" 
      Tag={Binding UserName} //If need, you can find the complete username on the Tag property of your menu item.                                                    
      FontFamily="Arial"...
```